# Telegram bot auto message

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, message

My English is a bit bad, I'll write as best I can. I am writing a telegram bot that will periodically send notifications by user_id, when you start the cycle of checking for new data in the request and sending it to the user, the whole code freezes and does not allow the user to complete more requests. I'm running a function through a thread, but I'm getting an error. Please help me to solve

```
bot.py

import requests
import json
import telebot
import buttonbot
import time
from telebot import types
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
import service
import threading
import bottoken

bot = Bot(token=bottoken)

notext = 'notext'

dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['help'])
async def online(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"ваш id: {message.from_user.id}")
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    await threading.Thread(target=service.run(user_id), daemon=True, name=None).start()
```

```
service.py

import requests
import json
import time
import threading
from data import data
from headers import headers
from aiogram import executor
import sched, time


notext = 'notext'

rt = ''

method = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{rt}/sendMessage"

async def get_updates(file_count=0):
    url = ""
    url4 = ""
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    response =  session.post(url, data=data)
    result = session.get(url4, data=data).json()
    return result['rows']

async def run(user_id):
    url = ""
    url2 = ""
    url3 = ""
    url4 = ""
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    response =  session.post(url, data=data)
    update_id = get_updates()[-1]['id']
    for _ in range(5):
       messages = get_updates(update_id)
        for message in messages:
            if update_id < message['id']:
                update_id = message['id']
                card = (f"New: {message['number']}")
                r = requests.post(method, data={
                    "chat_id": user_id,
                    "text": card
                    })
                time.sleep(60)
```

On startup, the console reports that the thread has started, but it will not send anything to the user

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-14' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py:407> exception=TypeError("object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "/root/home/vtk/./botvtk.py", line 34, in online
    await threading.Thread(target=service.run(user_id), daemon=True, name=None).start()
TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not callable
```

Comment: It would help if you could make a smaller reproducible example. Or you can try to narrow it down yourself: Is it a problem with async/await or the telegram-library